# C++: Function pointer that holds a method from a specific instance

Tags: c++, pointers, event-handling

So I'm currently working on an input manager for a C++ game. I was thinking about doing it as a `map<char, list<Listener::method>>`, so that when I register a button pressed, I call all the methods registered for the specific key.

Problem is, done like that I have to specify the instance which I want to call the method from. Is there a way to hold inside a variable not only the method but the caller instance?

Something like:

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo ();
    ~Foo ();
    void DoSomething();
};


Foo fooObject;

void(Foo::*fPtr)(void) = &fooObject::DoSomething;
(*fPtr)();
```

And that would call `fooObject`'s `DoSomething()`

Is it possible?

If not, could someone point me to a Event-Listener pattern? Doesnt have to be overcomplicated or threadsafe. Just the basic structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with member function pointers is you need an instance of the class to call them on.  You can't achieve this with just a pointer because the pointer only points to the function, and not the additional object you need to pass to the function (remember all member functions have an implicit first parameter that takes the class type).

You can use a `std::function` to have a function object that holds the object to call and the function to call on it.  If you have

```
std::function<void()> func = [&](){ return fooObject.DoSomething(); }; // Bind with a reference.  Use this if the object will live as long as the function to save on a copy
std::function<void()> func = [=](){ return fooObject.DoSomething(); }; // Bind with a copy. Use this if the function will outlive the object
```

then when you call `func` using `func()` it will run the body of he lambda which calls `DoSomething` on `fooObject`.

---

You can also use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to bind a member function pointer to a object to call it on but lambdas are generally preferred as the syntax is easy to use.

Comment: So seeing this I'm picturing doing a "bind list" using a  `map<char, list<std::function<void()>>>` so when I access a pair I can call all functions from their appropiate instances associated with a character. Am I far off or is it a possible way of doing it?

Comment: @EamonThornton That's what I'm suggesting.  When you build the map you create a list of the all the function you want that character to be associated with.  Just be careful about the object lifetimes.  I'd suggest starting off by capturing by copy at first to make sure it will work and then you can inspect the code to see if capturing by reference would be okay.

Comment: Really nice and helpful! I'll get into it right away, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to hold inside a variable not only the method but the caller instance?

Yes, you can *bind* method and object together.

Since *C++11* you have [`bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) utility.

---

A minimal example from your concept:

```
struct Foo {
  void foo();
};

void bar() {
  // your map
  std::map<char, std::function<void()>> actions;

  // Bind method and object together inside fn
  Foo foo;
  auto fn = std::bind(&Foo::foo, &foo);

  // Insert fn into map
  actions.emplace('f', fn);

  // call fn from map! Be careful about object lifetime
  actions['f']();
}
```

[Godbolt code](https://godbolt.org/z/vY_XBm)

---

Be careful because the "bind object" (`fn` in my example) will just store a *reference* to the object `foo`. Therefore, if you invoke `fn` after the object `foo` has been destroyed you will get an *undefined behaviour*.

---

In case you want to take care about object lifetime, you can copy it with a lambda function. For example:

```
auto fn = [foo]() { foo.foo(); }
```

Or use a custom structure and store a copied object inside.

Comment: That's pretty much how I envisioned it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "method from a specific instance".

1. You can hold a pointer to a member function of a class. Such pointers are not bound to any specific object.
2. You can use that function pointer on any object of the class.

Given

```
class Foo 
{ 
  public:
    Foo ();
    ~Foo ();
    void DoSomething();
};
```

Any class can hold a pointer to the `DoSomething` member function (you're calling it a method).

```
void(Foo::*fPtr)(void) = &Foo::DoSomething;
```

You would need an object to be able to call the member function. The calling syntax is a bit obtuse but here it is.

```
Foo foo = <some function call>;
(foo.*fPtr)();
```

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this functionality! I was trying to avoid it so I didn't have to have both a pointer to the member and the instance to "build" a full call to a method from a specific instance. Thanks anyways for clearing it up! I'll see what I can do!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `bind`-functionality to get function object having function parameteras already bound to arguments. By that, you can bind the object reference, which is implicitly the first parameter in any non-static member function, to the respective object for which you'd like to have the callback:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int x;
    Foo (int _x) : x(_x) {} ;
    void doSomething() { cout << x << endl; }
};


int main() {

    Foo fooObject1(1);
    Foo fooObject2(2);

    std::function<void ()> fx1 = std::bind(&Foo::doSomething,&fooObject1);
    std::function<void ()> fx2 = std::bind(&Foo::doSomething,&fooObject2);

    std::vector<std::function<void ()>> callbacks;
    callbacks.push_back(fx1);
    callbacks.push_back(fx2);

    for (auto f : callbacks) {
        f();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```